# Files are checked out on first upload

Tags: 2010, check-out

Ref: [Uploaded documents getting checked out by default in Sharepoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/75499/uploaded-documents-getting-checked-out-by-default-in-sharepoint-2010) which does not address an adequate answer, and the question is lacking details.

I am in explorer view, and I drag and drop a new file into a folder.
In versioning settings, I have "require check out" set to YES.
None of my metadeta columns are set to "required."

After dragging/dropping, the file(s) are checked out to me.  I would like them to be checked in on initial upload, considering I have no metadata required to be entered.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do this out of the box. Do you have the means to create an event receiver?

Comment: @ErinL I think yes, but don't know where to begin.

Comment: It is answered in another answer, http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/75532/1806. This is the behavior of that setting, same occurs in 2013/2016.

Comment: @EricAlexander I want to normally require all files to be checked out before editing, only on first upload I would like them to be in the checked-in state.  I just uploaded it, I don't want to continue editing at this time.

Comment: Begin by downloading Visual Studio (on a development server to test before you deploy into production), creating a new SharePoint solution and add an Event Receiver to detect when a file is uploaded (there are tons of tutorials), and add code to check the file in.